# JPA entities updated implicitly by new query

Tags: java, jpa

THe title can't definitely reflect my question, however I don't know how to express. I have a JPA entity (`VatOperatorBalance` which has a field `saleBalance`), lets say I retrieve the entity at the first time, and get a entity (`VatOperatorBalance@3d6396f5`), its `saleBalance` is `100.0`. Now there are other operations which has modified the `saleBalance` to `200`, now I query from database and get a new entity (`VatOperatorBalance@10f8ed`), sure the `saleBalance` of this entity is `200.0`. However what make me confused it the `saleBalance` of the old entity (`VatOperatorBalance@3d6396f5`) is also `200.0`.

All these queries and operations are in a single transaction, and the query isn't by `EntityManager.find(java.lang.Class<T> entityClass, java.lang.Object primaryKey)` which will return entity from cache.

Below is my code

```
@Rollback(true)
@Test
public void testSale_SingleBet_OK() throws Exception {
    // prepare request ...

    // query the VatOperatorBalance first
    VatOperatorBalance oldBalance = this.getVatOperatorBalanceDao().findByOperator("OPERATOR-111");
    //this.entityManager.detach(oldBalance);
    logger.debug("------ oldBalance(" + oldBalance + ").");

    // the operation which will modify the oldBalance 
    Context saleReqCtx = this.getDefaultContext(TransactionType.SELL_TICKET.getRequestType(),
            clientTicket);
    saleReqCtx.setGameTypeId(GameType.VAT.getType() + "");
     Context saleRespCtx = doPost(this.mockRequest(saleReqCtx));
    RaffleTicket respTicket = (RaffleTicket) saleRespCtx.getModel();

    this.entityManager.flush();
    this.entityManager.clear();

    // assert vat sale balance
    VatOperatorBalance newBalance = this.getVatOperatorBalanceDao().findByOperator("OPERATOR-111");
    logger.debug("------ newBalance(" + newBalance + ").");
    assertEquals(oldBalance.getSaleBalance().add(respTicket.getTotalAmount()).doubleValue(), newBalance
            .getSaleBalance().doubleValue(), 0);
}
```

This testcase will fail, I don't understand why this will happen. JPA entity manager will update all entities of same entity type? The `oldBalance` entity and `newBlance` entity have same `entityId`, however they are different Java instance, what happened in JPA entity manager? If I detach the `oldBalance` entity from `EntityManager`, testcase will pass.

Note: my test is using Spring4.0.5 and JPA2.1

> @piet.t since the entityManager would recognize it is the same entity by its primary key (feel free to try it). So all changes made to this entity through the same entityManager will all affect the same java instance

So in a entity manager, a given entity type with given primary key, there should be only one java instance or managed entity(if query from entity manager, no matter what query criteria, by id or not, the same java instance(managed entity) will be returned).

However in my test case, the entity 'oldBalance' will be updated by "**the operation which will modify the oldBalance**", and then the call of entityManager.clear() will detach all entities managed by this entity manager, that says 'oldBalance' is detached too.

And the 'newBalance' is managed entity then, that is why they have different java instance identifier.  If 'oldBalance' is managed, for example by call entityManager.merge(), it will be the same instance of 'newBalance'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most of your confusion does arise from the `flush()`-call in your code.

1. Calling `flush` will always store the changed value to the database - that's the whoe point of calling `flush`. When using transactions the changed value might still not be visible via other connections due to the databases transaction machanism but your entityManager will only see the changed value.
2. Without the `clear`-call your query - even though it is not using `find` - would still return the same instance that was previously created (VatOperatorBalance@3d6396f5) since the entityManager would recognize it is the same entity by its primary key (feel free to try it). So all changes made to this entity through the same entityManager will all affect the same java instance while modifications through another entity manager will most likely cause an exception because the entity was update from another transaction.
3. Some queries might cause an implicit `flush`, since the cached changes might influence the query-result, so all changes have to be written to the database before executing the query to get a correct result-set.

I hope that does help a bit.